# ModelMultipleChoiceField as a multi-column table

Tags: django, forms

In Django, how do I render a ModelMultipleChoiceField as a multi-column `<table>`?

```
fav = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(Show.objects.all(),
                                     widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
```

I want this field to render as a multi-column table. Which is the best way to do that?

To clarify, I want the rendering to take N objects and render an HTML `<table>` with one checkbox in each cell, across e.g. three columns in each `<tr>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Django is hard-coded to use a `<ul>` here. See the [widgets.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/9c487b5974ee7e7f196079611d7352364e8873ed/django/forms/widgets.py#L569) code.

You could subclass the `CheckboxSelectMultiple` widget class and provide your own `.render()` method using tables.

Comment: LOL, that's my old blog post! :-D woot! hehe also google "the inner workings of the deathstarwidget" ;)

Comment: http://skyl.org/log/post/skyl/2011/01/wherein-the-inner-workings-of-the-deathstarwidget-are-revealed/